# Slick slider displaying one image at a time not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, slider

I am using fade slick slider i want to display one image at a time but my slider is not working:

```
<head>
    <link href="js/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="js/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="js/slick.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/slick.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.fade').slick({
            dots: true,
            infinite: true,
            speed: 500,
            fade: true,
            cssEase: 'linear'
         });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="fade">
        <div>
            <img src="images/ProductName/6.jpg" alt="" />

                <img src="images/ProductName/6.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Above code is working to display image but slider is not applying.I want image to be display one by one but it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add Jquery Library. "". Try this.

```js
 $(document).on('ready', function() {
      $(".regular").slick({
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3
      });
      $(".center").slick({
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        centerMode: true,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3
      });
      $(".variable").slick({
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        variableWidth: true
      });
    });
```

```css
  html, body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .slider {
        width: 50%;
        margin: 100px auto;
    }

    .slick-slide {
      margin: 0px 20px;
    }

    .slick-slide img {
      width: 100%;
    }

    .slick-prev:before,
    .slick-next:before {
        color: black;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Slick Playground</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
<head>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>


<section class="regular slider">
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=1">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=2">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=3">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=4">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=5">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=6">
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="center slider">
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=1">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=2">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=3">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=4">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=5">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=6">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=7">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=8">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=9">
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="variable slider">
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=1">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300?text=2">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x300?text=3">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300?text=4">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=5">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300?text=6">
    </div>
  </section>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>

  </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have to add [jquery](https://code.jquery.com/) , then remove the `div` enclosing the two images , that's why it shows the images at same time , also add `$.ready` function to your script to ensure dom loading.

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bRIMOs/h7ksmc0k/)

```js
$( document ).ready(function(){
  $('.fade').slick({
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 500,
    fade: true,
    cssEase: 'linear'
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>

<div style="background-color:gray">
<form id="form1" runat="server">
     <div class="fade" style="width:40%;margin:auto">
          <img src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/images/Simplest-Responsive-jQuery-Image-Lightbox-Plugin-simple-lightbox.jpg" alt="" />
      <img src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/images/Cross-browser-Image-Carousel-Plugin-For-jQuery-carouselOnPC.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
    </form>
</div>
```